# Java webstart replaces jnlp with wifi login page html

Tags: java-web-start

My webstart runs fine whenever there is internet connection. It also runs fine when I disconnect from wifi. But it does not work if my computer is connected to public wifi (ie. coffeeshop, airport, etc) such that if I open a browser it forwards me to a html page that asks me to click on a button to connect to internet.

Basically Java webstart thinks that the html welcome page is the new update to my jnlp file so it replaces my jnlp with the welcome page html. Of course that will fail to parse, so I get a parse error and I cannot recover from it unless I completely remove my webstart application from cache and re-download and re-install it.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug report to OpenJDK:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8079874

Unfortunately it's marked as incomplete. Evidently I wasn't clear about what the problem is. I'll try to get in touch with them to see which part is not clear.